# I got this warning error when Flutter Firebase setup command "dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

To recompile executables, first run `dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli`.
Installed executable flutterfire.
Warning: Pub installs executables into $HOME/.pub-cache/bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.):

export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Simply this method worked for me**

> Step 1 : Open Terminal run this command

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

[image]

> Step 2 : then run this command below

```
dart pub global activate fvm
```

[image]